# Is there an ARM repository for Arch Linux?

Tags: chroot, repository, android, arch-arm, phone

I'm trying to create a chroot for my rooted Android phone. I want to do this with the `arch_bootstrap.sh` script found on the wiki, but I can't find an ARM repository.

My PC is x86_64 Arch Linux and my mobile is a HTC Desire running Cyanogenmod 7.

Comment: Linux is only the kernel, everything else is different on Android.  Are you expecting something similar to Debian or OpenWRT?

Comment: Yes, I know. I was talking about arch linux; I never mentioned linux in the context of the kernel. Arch Linux is a distro of GNU Linux

Comment: CM 7?? Consider an update, we're on v13 now...

Answer (score 8):

No. There is no official Arch Linux repository for ARM. However, there is a fork of Arch for ARM: http://archlinuxarm.org/